# Have the details in Voevodsky's original approach to Milnor's conjecture been filled in?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In [Bloch-Kato conjecture for $\mathbb{Z}/2$-coefficients and algebraic Morava $K$-theories](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/K-theory/0076/) Voevodsky claimed a proof of Milnor's conjecture under some assumptions. Later he came up with a different line of attack.

Have the details in the original approach been filled in? The conjectural pieces were:

1. Resolution of singularities (still unknown)
2. The algebra $H^*(k, \mu_l^{\otimes *})$ for $l\neq \mathrm{char}\:k$ being Koszul. It appears this was addressed by Positselski but is it fully resolved?
3. The existence of algebraic Morava $K$-theories with some nice properties. Is this fully known?

It is also possible that some intermediate arguments are not completely correct. Is there any information on that?